# Solidity: Handling multi-mappings with multiple entries per key

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

I am wondering how I would implement a smart contract that would allow me to iterate through a list of (possibly matching) results in a mapping in order to "find" the right one to get. In a way, I'm trying to recreate what in SQL would be a `SELECT * FROM mytable` and then iterating through the returned rows. Obviously, this doesn't translate well to Blockchain/Solidity.

So here's my example:

```
mapping (address => bytes32[]) private map;
```

So for an/any address, I want to be able to store an arbitrary number of uint8-bytes32-pairs. So far, so good. Now retrieving a single one, knowing EXACTLY the uint8-"key" is fairly easy:

```
function getOne(address a, uint8 b) public view returns(bytes32) {
    return map[a][b];
}
```

For iterating through all, this would be done on the client side:

```
function getAll(address a) public view returns(bytes32[]) {
    return map[a];
}
```

Now, I can go though this array on my client-side and fetch the one I need using `getOne()`.

Anyhow, this feels like quite some overhead. Is there some more elegant/efficient way to do this in Solidity?

Comment: Since `map[a]` is an array you can iterate until a value is found and return it.

Comment: Thats true. Anyhow, this might be very costly, as each iteration will cost me gas. So I'd rather do the iteration on client-side